# When dataSource.getConnection() return null in jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I have doubt about  `javax.sql.DataSource` interface method

```
Connection getConnection() throws SQLException;
```

I use *apache commons dbcp datasource*, and I want to know in which case this method can return `null` value?

Comment: If connected to db in success, getConnection returns the connection, unless an exception raised.  Null is never returned.

Comment: And in general only if the Javadoc says so, [which it doesn't](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection()).